# SharePoint 2013 Patching using Trevors patch script

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, patching

[Patching script.](https://github.com/Nauplius/SharePoint-Patch-Script) From this script, there is a command `Install-SPPatch -Path C:\Updates -Pause -KeepSearchPaused:$true -SilentInstall`

We can run this command, we can keep the search in the paused state until patch installation is completed on all servers, but how to start the search services once all the patches are installed in all servers in the farm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script has the cmdlets to do that, but this is what you would do:

```
    $ssas = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication

    foreach ($ssa in $ssas) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Resuming the Search Service Application: $($ssa.DisplayName)"
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow '    This could take a few minutes...'
        Resume-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication -Identity $ssa | Out-Null
    }
```